# Creating a new dataframe based on unique columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'city':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'V':[1,2,3,1,2,3],'O':[33,44,55,66,77,88]})
```

Now I wanted to create a new dataframe which has unique elements of column V along with the corresponding values from the 'O' column.
Output-

```
   city   1   2   3
0   a    33  44  55
1   b    66  77  88
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pivot_table` for this:

```
df = df.pivot_table('O', ['city'], 'V')
print(df)

V      1   2   3
city
a     33  44  55
b     66  77  88
```